How to replace string in R?
I have been trying to replace )  bracket space to )| bracket pipe but it seems str_replace uses regex which I am not able to figure out for this pattern. It should be simple if one knows regex but I am struggling at this atleast for now.
I have tried several codes to figure out the regex pattern but have not been able to crack it so far:
library(tidyverse)

tibble(value = "ASO QUANTITATIVE (ANTI STROPTOLYSION O) 52.2|0 - 200|IU/ml") %>% 
  mutate(value = str_replace(value,").* ",")|"))

Appreciate any help here.

str_replace(value,"\\) ",")|") - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/regular-expressions.html#escaping

Thanks alot ...this worked. If you can add this to the answer then I will accept it & close the question.
